# Text inside a textbox in Excel VBA userform expands horizontally

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

[image]

When I type text into my userform's textbox the text keeps going right non-stop and I can't see the whole text. I need it to go down automatically when the text length reaches the limit of the textbox.

The textbox's text keeps overflowing to the right and I need it to go to the next line when it reaches the limit of the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the property `.Multiline = True` with your TextBox.

Comment: and `.WordWrap = True` as well :)

Comment: Thank you. I'm kind of new and havent's used the tool too much. Sorry.